# Jquery and SharePoint Currency Field

Tags: javascript, jquery, list-form, currency-field

I have a form with multiple SharePoint fields set as "currency".  How do I put a currency field value into a variable? I've tried several version, such as:

```
var txt01TotCash = $("input[id='Total_x0020_Cash__2abd298c-4fee-401a-b51a-d48afd27a395_$CurrencyField']").text();
```

and

```
var txt01TotCash = $("input[id='Total_x0020_Cash__2abd298c-4fee-401a-b51a-d48afd27a395_$CurrencyField']").val();
```

and

```
var txt01TotCash = $("input[title='Total Cash']").val();
```

The error I get is `val is not a function` or `text is not a function`.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By Looking at your code, Either jQuery is not loaded properly or your selector for currency is wrong:

Try below code:

1. **Using Plain JavaScript**:

```
    var currencyField = document.querySelector("input[title^='Currency']"); //Here "Currency" is display name of field.
    var currencyValue = currencyField.value;
    currencyField.addEventListener('change', function() {
        var currencyValue = currencyField.value;
    });
    console.log(currencyValue);
```

2. **Using jQuery**:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var currencyValue = $("input[title^='Currency']").val(); //Here "Currency" is display name of field.

        $("input[title^='Currency']").change(function() {
            currencyValue = $("input[title^='Currency']").val();
            console.log(currencyValue);
        });
    });
```

Make sure jQuery file is loaded properly.

Comment: Hi, does this answers your question? If yes, please accept it as an answer.